# Regex to compare natural numbers

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm learning PCRE2 regular expressions. How can they be used to compare two natural numbers of arbitrary length?

I read on Stackoverflow that for practical purposes this is inefficient. But I'm asking for educational purposes.

Need to compare two numbers given as `<number1> ? <number2>`. And replace `?` with the comparison result: ">", "<" or "=".

Input example:

```
123 ? 456
90 ? 530
87234790 ? 1
15 ? 15
```

Expected output:

```
123 < 456
90 < 530
87234790 > 1
15 = 15
```

I've tried, but don't quite understand how to do it.

I'm new to Stackoverflow. Sorry if such educational questions are not welcome here.

Comment: Regexes aren’t designed for that

Comment: Regexes do not do math operations, which means that what you're asking isn't possible. You can do it in any programming language you'd like, or using Excel.

Comment: @klee It seems to me that PCRE should allow you to do this. Unfortunately, I don't have enough time right now to figure this out.

Comment: You might be able to compare number with regexes, but it absolutely totally not worth it. And even so, you cannot really compare numbers of "arbitrary" length, you would have to decide for a maximum (which would be quite small). Why in the world would you even think about it, when there are so many ways to compare numbers fast and easy.

Comment: btw,, your question is not "educational", it is a XY problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem - which practically means you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: You would [use a callback function for this (e.g. PHP demo)](https://tio.run/##bY9bC4JAEIXf91ccQlilsNTsgpavPfZeEbaNJa22WEEQ/nZbN7o8BANzZuc7hx11VE0TJ8vFkjGL7mmhJGHGPT9AgmE4YtOBFmEwYJOxHwzHZvSYF7Yt5NGvC6qiw7YiJVNBW5FKuUvFyeZ9e73vOlgnMKLPe8hupbjm59K2Coc9GGCJQukEPtORgK4807uVt0EM3f2Ngxb7grEBa5C80Bee/4fnPDKh9Su7ouutKmEsbgcdt@VeonWbH9Q9vC9z9JUkjufPQ8Sa5gk).

Comment: Thank you. But I want to understand how this can be done with "pure" regex

Comment: @Michail I would be very grateful if you would help me understand how to do this with regexes, as soon as you have time.

Comment: @klee I cannot tell if the answer provided by Michail is correct and I don't even want to know. The question is wrong in the first place and Michail's answer, no matter if it is correct or not, cannot help you learn regex. I would also not use it to compare two numbers; parsing the input strings as numbers and comparing the values using `<` is much shorter and more clear, no matter what language you use. The only good answer to your question is: Maybe it is possible but it is not worth it. And it is definitely neither a good way to learn regex, nor something to do in production.

Comment: @axiac I could have been misunderstood due to my bad English. I don't want help about how to compare numbers using a computer. I'm not PCRE-newbie and know all the basic techniques. But I want to learn advanced techniques that the community owns. Solving the "unfriendly" for PCRE problem of comparing numbers is just one of the ways to study such techniques. And I am very grateful to Michail for his master class despite those who wrote that it is impossible to solve this using PCRE. But I don't quite understand Michail's solution yet. It takes time to study it...

Comment: @klee I understand now. Usually newbies come to Stackoverflow asking for regexes to do things (like checking if a number is inside a range of numbers) that can be done using complex regexes but can be done easier without regex (because regex, despite being that powerful, is not the appropriate tool for such requests).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have sketched an approximate regex.

Regex:

```
/^(*:>)(?=(?(?=(\d(?:\ \?\ |(?1))\d))
   (?(?=\1.)(*ACCEPT:<))
   (?:(?=\d(\d*+\D++)(((?(3)\3))\d))
      (?>(?=(\d)\2\4\5) |
      (?:1\2\4[0]|2\2\4[01]|3\2\4[0-2]|4\2\4[0-3]|5\2\4[0-4]|6\2\4[0-5]|7\2\4[0-6]|8\2\4[0-7]|9)(*ACCEPT) |
      (*ACCEPT:<))
   .)++(*ACCEPT:=)
)).*?\K\?/gmx
```

Replacer:
`$*MARK`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zo10KX/1)

## Some explanation

General strategy: we should compare digits of number1 with corresponding digits of number2.

`(?(?=\1.)(*ACCEPT:<))` - number1 have less digits than number2, so number1 < number2. We don't consider numbers starting with series of "0"

`(?:(?=\d(\d*+\D++)(((?(3)\3))\d))` - start loop through the corresponding digits of given numbers

`(?=(\d)\2\4\5)` - if digit1 is equal to digit2 then go to next loop iteration to check next pair of digits

`(?:1\2\4[0]|2\2\4[01]|3\2\4[0-2]|4\2\4[0-3]|5\2\4[0-4]|6\2\4[0-5]|7\2\4[0-6]|8\2\4[0-7]|9)(*ACCEPT)` - digit1 > digit2, so number1 > number2, exit

`(*ACCEPT:<))` - digit1 < digit2, so number1 < number2, exit

`.)++(*ACCEPT:=)` - all corresponding digits are equal, so number1 = number2

Comment: Thank you very match! I need some time to study your solution and techniques...

Comment: And I am very unpleasantly surprised that regex101.com does not support all the PCRE syntax.

Comment: I've been studying this solution half the night. It works and it's great! It has a bunch of advanced techniques! And one of them is an amazing alternative to the recently discussed one: Different matches can be replaced with different values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930041/one-regex-to-replace-some-different-things

Comment: This now works on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/sg8CVZ/1

Comment: @FirasDib Wow! Thank you. Confirm that now regex101 is ok with this regex. I'll correct an answer